# pass secret key over tls\ssl

Tags: tls, secret-sharing

Let's say that I have a client and server connected over SSL\TLS. 
Once the handshake is done, both sides have a shared secret key that they will use to encrypt\decrypt the data.

Can I use this secure connection to pass symmetric keys for other usage? ( hardware based transmitter )

Comment: I'm a little confused. You have an encrypted channel and you want to pass sensitive and secret data over this channel? Yes, you can do this because that's what the encrypted channel is for: to communicate secret data. Are there threats that could break this channel? Yes. But I'm not sure if that's what you are asking about.

Comment: Dev1 1 has a HW transmitter that encrypts the data with AES-256 symetric key before sending it.
Dev2 has a HW receiver that decrypts the data using the same secret key , the enc\dec is pure hw, where the key needs to be rotated every few seconds. 
So  :
1.use ECDH over public connection to exchange the key every few sec.
2. create ssl session and send the key over that connection
3. use ECDH over secure ssl connection to exchange the key every few sec.
Since I will have an ssl connection between the devices anyway for Auth,  I am looking at options 1 and 3.

Comment: I'm not sure your comment addresses my question at all. I think you have an X/Y problem here.

Comment: You still haven't addressed my questions. You have a secure communication channel, and you want to use this channel to pass a key for another encryption process. Am I correct? If so, My original comment stands: secure, encrypted channels are created in order to pass secret information (like keys).

Comment: You are correct , Thanks for the clear answer.
Someone told me that is not secure to pass "symetric keys" even not over a secure connection. I didn't think so and wanted to confirm my opinion.

Comment: I have 2 responses to that: 1) TLS/SSL have vulnerabilities which could expose the channel. You need to address those issues when you assess the threat. 2) What is the alternative?

Comment: The altrnative is to use ECDH so both sides will generate same shared secret . assume the sides are already authenticated.